# PySIde QPropertyAnimation lagging when running another function in parallel

Tags: python, pyside, qpropertyanimation

I have a simple slide in animation of a main menu.:

I have a button that triggers this animation and another function. The other function just sets text in a textbox and opens a dialog widget. The problem is the animation becomes very glitchy/laggy when I call that other function at the same time as starting the animation. When I remove the call to the function, the animation is smooth. As a test, I also tried replacing the function with a single print statement printing "Clicked", and that was enough to cause the animation to lag.

In the following code I have two buttons. One that slides the menu without calling any other function, and another button that slides the menu with calling another function, in this case print. You should see the first button results In a smooth animation and the other button results in a laggy animation.

```
import sys
from PySide.QtGui import *
from PySide.QtCore import *


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()
        self.central = QFrame()
        self.mainLayout = QVBoxLayout(self.central)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.central)
        self.slide_wo_printing = QPushButton("Slide the menu without printing") #Pushing this button will slide the menu without printing anything. It will be smooth
        self.slide_wo_printing.clicked.connect(self.slideMainMenu)

        self.slide_w_printing = QPushButton("Slide the menu with printing")     #Pushing this button will slide the menu and print something. It will be laggy
        self.slide_w_printing.clicked.connect(lambda: print("Button Clicked"))
        self.slide_w_printing.clicked.connect(self.slideMainMenu)

        self.mainLayout.addWidget(self.slide_wo_printing)
        self.mainLayout.addWidget(self.slide_w_printing)

        self.resize(700,800)

        self.mainMenu = QFrame(self)
        self.mainMenu.setStyleSheet("QFrame{background-color:lightblue;}")
        self.mainMenu.resize(200,700)
        self.mainMenuLayout = QVBoxLayout(self.mainMenu)

        self.first_btn = QPushButton("Button 1")
        self.mainMenuLayout.addWidget(self.first_btn)
        self.second_btn = QPushButton("Button 2")
        self.mainMenuLayout.addWidget(self.second_btn) 
        self.third_btn = QPushButton("Button 3")
        self.mainMenuLayout.addWidget(self.third_btn)
        self.mainMenu.move(QPoint(0,65))
        self.mainMenu.show() 


        self.ani = QPropertyAnimation(
            self.mainMenu, b"geometry", parent=self, duration=200
        )

        self.mainMenuShown = True



    def slideMainMenu(self):
        if(self.mainMenuShown):
            self.ani.setStartValue(QRect(0,65,200,700))
            self.ani.setEndValue(QRect(-200,65,200,700))
            self.ani.start()
        else:
            self.ani.setStartValue(QRect(-200,65,200,700))
            self.ani.setEndValue(QRect(0,65,200,700))
            self.ani.start()

        self.mainMenuShown = not self.mainMenuShown



if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    mainWin = MainWindow()
    mainWin.show()
    ret = app.exec_()
    sys.exit( ret )
```

Is there anyway I can get around this? Pressing the main menu button is supposed to change the page as well as slide the menu back in. It seems that I cannot do both.

Comment: again: 1) Provide a [mre], 2) If the GUI freezes that implies that some part of the code is not well designed

Comment: @eyllanesc Hi eyllanesc, I have added an mre that illustrates the issue.

Comment: I do not reproduce your problem with PySide 1.2.4 on Linux.